# Formatting in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, formatting

Would anyone know if there is any code or any quick way of formatting this information into time so I can get an average...

0 Days 1 Hours 8 Minutes
0 Days 10 Hours 16 Minutes
4 Days 12 Hours 0 Minutes

Any help would be greatly appreciated totally stuck on this

Many Thanks 
Paula

Comment: do you want the average between 0 Days 1 Hours 8 Minutes and 0 Days 10 Hours 16 Minutes and 4 Days 12 Hours 0 Minutes ?

Comment: I have a list of about 200 numbers that I need to get the average of.. but they all appear in that format and rather than me changing each one manually to get an average I was wondering if there is any quicker way of doing this?

Comment: ok but is the average of those 3 numbers 2388 minutes ?

Comment: I would need it in Hrs:mm:ss so I get 35:52:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get those numbers in minutes using this formula next to them

```
=(LEFT(A1;FIND(" ";A1)-1))*24*60 + MID(A1;FIND("Days";A1)+5;(FIND("Hours";A1)-1)-(FIND("Days";A1)+5))*60 + (MID(A1;FIND("Hours";A1)+6;(FIND("Minutes";A1)-1)-(FIND("Hours";A1)+6)))*1
```

then you do a =AVERAGE of those minutes, so if we suppose we have that average in h4, you do

```
=INT(H4/60) & ":" &MOD(MOD(H4;1440);60) &":00"
```

you always get 00 as seconds of course. let me know if you need further assistance :)

Comment: I cant get the first part of the formula to work I have pasted my information into a new document... but when I put the information into cell A1 so it should reference cell A1 it keeps throwing it up as an error when trying to put it into minutes... :S

Comment: you mean this formula =(LEFT(A1;FIND(" ";A1)-1))*24*60 + MID(A1;FIND("Days";A1)+5;(FIND("Hours";A1)-1)-(FIND("Days";A1)+5))*60 + (MID(A1;FIND("Hours";A1)+6;(FIND("Minutes";A1)-1)-(FIND("Hours";A1)+6)))*1 ?

Comment: yea that formaula... it just says the formula you typed contains an error and when I hit ok then it takes me to the first A1 in the formula =(LEFT(A1;FIND(

Comment: what if you try a simple =LEFT(A1;5)

Comment: Yea it seems to like =LEFT(A1,5) but now its throwing me down the line to each of the A1s

Comment: so you need to use commas (,) instead of semi commas (;). Try

Comment: =(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))*24*60 + MID(A1,FIND("Days",A1)+5,(FIND("Hours",A1)-1)-(FIND("Days",A1)+5))*60 + (MID(A1,FIND("Hours",A1)+6,(FIND("Minutes",A1)-1)-(FIND("Hours",A1)+6)))*1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81948/discussion-between-gotrekk-and-paula).

Comment: Thats it working perfectly now thank you so so much for your help...uve saved me A LOT of time :D

Answer (score 1):

If your data format is a column, copy your data to another column then use `Data>Text to Columns>Defined` use space for separating character. Now your data will be like this:

[image]

Then use a formula to sum them like `B2+(D2*1/24)+(F2*1/24/60)`. the result should be like this:

[image]